# Trying to make a snap for Lollypop Music Player

Tags: 16.04, python, snap, autotools

I am trying to snap [Lollypop](https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop), my favourite music player. The author has already made a flatpak, but since they don't work on Ubuntu 16.04 by default, I tried to create my [snapcraft.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Zap123/13478830ec1f670c61d20525df10a65b).

The problem is that during compile time the python path get set to an absolute value like `/usr/lib/python...`, but at runtime it should be something like `/snap/lollypop/current/usr/lib/python...`, see `lollypop.in`.
I believe that during compile time it should detect the containerized python path, but it doesn't seem the case.

Anyone have an idea? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could be a duplicate of my question here: https://askubuntu.com/q/906199/26246 but not flagging it to be verified by another or the OP.