# How to setup PYTHONPATH for a snap package?

Tags: python, packaging, snap

I'm trying to snap package a non-pure python project. I used `python` plugin with custom build/install scripts.

This project contains 2 python packages that are required for desktop app:

- `alfanous` (API)
- `alfanous-desktop` (Qt PySide GUI)

**`snapcraft.yaml`** file:

```
name: alfanous
version: "0.7.8"
summary: Alfanous
description: GNU hello prints a friendly greeting.
  This is part of the snapcraft tour at http://snapcraft.io/create/
#confinement: strict
confinement: devmode

apps:
  alfanous-gui:
    command: usr/bin/alfanous-desktop
    #desktop: usr/share/applications/my-app.desktop
  alfanous-cli:
    command: usr/bin/alfanous-console

parts:
  alfanous-git:
    build-packages:
      #- python
      - sqlite3
      - pyside-tools
      - qt4-linguist-tools
      - python-babel
      - qt4-qmake
      - python-setuptools
      #- python-pyparsing
      #- perl
    #plugin: make
    plugin: python
    python-version: python2
    #source: https://github.com/Alfanous-team/alfanous/archive/0.7.8.tar.gz
    source: https://github.com/Alfanous-team/alfanous.git
    source-type: git
    source-depth: 1
    #source-tag: 0.7.8
    build: |
      make build
    install: |
      echo _______#######:$(pwd)
      #make install_api 
      make install_api DESTDIR=$SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL
      make install_desktop DESTDIR=$SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL
    stage-packages:
      - python-pyparsing
      - python-pyside
      #- epydoc
      #- sphinx
      - python-babel
      - python-setuptools
    python-packages:
      - pyparsing
      - pyside
      - babel
```

The snap package is built and installed without errors. However, if i try to run it:

```
$ alfanous.alfanous-cli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/bin/alfanous-console", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/snap/alfanous/x3/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'alfanous==0.7.29' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

My first suspect is non-complete `PYTHONPATH`, trying to debug:

```
snap run --shell alfanous.alfanous-cli
env | grep -i python
```

brings nothing.

and both packages are there:

```
$ ls /snap/alfanous/current/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
alfanous                        alfanousDesktop
alfanous-0.7.29-py2.7.egg-info  alfanousDesktop-0.7.29-py2.7.egg-info
```

How could I setup `PYTHONPATH` correctly? Shouldn't the python plugin take care of that?

snapcraft v2.28 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64Bit

Comment: @knotech, thanks u , I've added my build host & tool version to the question. btw, I'm not looking to install alfanous into my host, but to create & distribute its snap package.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. Hope you get it resolved.

Comment: @knotech, thank u , :) i face same package when I look for snappy doc in the web. Alfanous install and run well manually.  that's why i suspect some thing to do with snap itself or my snapcraft.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `alfanous-console` to print `sys.path` and rebuild the snap:

```
['/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/bin',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/snap/alfanous/x4/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

It seems clear the `snap` does not include `site-packages` to `PYTHONPATH` where my target package installs itself.

- So I have to modify its install path
- Or report this to snap team to add `usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

  Related [bug report #1670749 : 
  classic confinement requires manually setting PATH and PYTHONPATH](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1670749)

  The suggested solution there didn't work:

  ```
  apps:
    alfanous-gui:
      command: usr/bin/alfanous-desktop
      environment:
        PATH: $SNAP/usr/bin:$SNAP/bin/:$PATH
        PYTHONPATH: $SNAP/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$SNAP/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
      #desktop: usr/share/applications/my-app.desktop
    alfanous-cli:
      command: usr/bin/alfanous-console
      environment:
        PATH: $SNAP/usr/bin:$SNAP/bin/:$PATH
        PYTHONPATH: $SNAP/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$SNAP/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
  ```

  Because of that weird path pointing to host `/home` folder

  ```
  ['/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/bin',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
   '/home/sneetsher/Desktop/sandbox/alfanous-snap',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
   '/snap/alfanous/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
  ```